# Redmine - incompatible versions for Bundler

Tags: bundler, redmine

I'm trying to install the 2.3.2 version of Redmine being offline. When I launch the command:

> bundle install --without postgresql --local

I get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem 'ruby-openid': 
In Gemfile:
  rack-openid (>= 0) ruby depends on
    ruby-openid (>= 2.1.8) ruby

  ruby-openid (2.1.4)
```

I understand the problem but how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to install a version newer than 2.1.8 of ruby-openid as only these versions are supported by the rack-openid gem which is required by Redmine.

You could download the current version of the gem (2.2.3) from [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-openid) and transfer that file to your server. The you can run

```
gem install ruby-openid-2.2.3.gem
```

to install the gem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need OpenID authentication, you can exclude it:

```
bundle install --without postgresql openid --local
```